# How to configure memory and vcore on hadoop YARN multinode cluster?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I want to implement hadoop YARN on multinode cluster, So I want to ask. Should I write about memory and vcore configuration in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml only on master(namenode), or should I write it also on slave(datanode) with the same configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Just write it on master node and restart yarn/hadoop, It will publish those changes on all the slaves.

PS: [Cloudera blog on how to configure YARN](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-2/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_11_4.html)